# Copy all dictionary items to a specific range efficiently

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

I have a dictionary containing a bunch of values that I want to print in a range of cells (a column) in a swift and efficient manner.
This range already contains values, that might or might not be the same as in the dictionary.

The first code I used after filling the dictionary was the following:

```
For i = 1 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    dKey = (Cells(i, 1))
    If Not Cells(i, 2) = dict(dKey) Then Cells(i, 2) = dict(dKey)
Next i
```

This simply loops the range, and replaces every value that isn't the same as in the dictionary.
*The range values are the same as they dictionary keys*
For the sake of this test, let's assume that each cell is different, so last row is `Cells(i, 2) = dict(dKey)` to write in each cell.

Now, to me this looks like it could end up writing a whole lot to the sheet, so I figured I could dump it all in one go.

I could only find how to print an array, using the following method:

```
Set destination = Range("B1")
Set destination = destination.Resize(UBound(arr), 1)
destination.Value = Application.Transpose(arr)
```

While that seems fast, my data is in a dictionary still. I tried converting my dictionary to an array first with:

```
ReDim arr(0 To dict.Count) As Variant
For i = 0 To dict.Count - 1
   arr(i) = dict.Items()(i)
Next i
```

But it turns out, this in itself might take more time (in my test at least) than just printing the dictionary.
With `10 000` rows, this approach was slower, but with `100 000` rows, it was faster. Thus the conversion seems to take me a second either way, but the "printing" is much faster.

**Is there a way to do something similar with the dictionary without converting it, making it faster for both scenarios?**

Comment: Scripting Dictionary has both `Keys` and `Items` properties both of which directly return arrays: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object  Your issue would be with `Transpose()` which has a limit around 65k I think.

Comment: @TimWilliams That works very well. Saves a few lines of code to just use `arr = dict.Keys` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this.

Reshaping the key/item arrays into a single 2-D array avoids the `Transpose()` limitation

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim dict As Object, n As Long, t, arrK, arrV, data
    
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    
    t = Timer
    For n = 1 To 100000
        dict.Add n, "Val_" & n
    Next n
    Debug.Print "Fill dictionary", Timer - t

    t = Timer
    arrK = dict.keys
    arrV = dict.items
    ReDim data(1 To UBound(arrK) - 1, 1 To 2)
    For n = 1 To UBound(arrK) - 1
        data(n, 1) = arrK(n - 1)
        data(n, 2) = arrV(n - 1)
    Next n
    ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Resize(UBound(data, 1), 2).Value = data
    Debug.Print "Add to range", Timer - t
    
End Sub
```

output:

```
Fill dictionary       0.3984375 
Add to range          0.296875
```

Comment: You can actually do this: `ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Resize(dict.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.Keys)` and
`ActiveSheet.Range("C1").Resize(dict.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.Items)` for up to 65535 items. But the interesting part is that this might be faster 20-30 milliseconds up to 15000 items, but after that the above array approach becomes faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can speed up the Dictionary->Array conversion significantly.

It turns out that for some reason, looping through a Dictionary is much, much faster when using an iterator.
Try replacing the code

```
ReDim arr(0 To dict.Count) As Variant
For i = 0 To dict.Count - 1
   arr(i) = dict.Items()(i)
Next i
```

with

```
ReDim Arr(0 To Dict.Count) As Variant
Dim it As Variant
Dim i as Long
i=0
For Each it In Dict.Items
   Arr(i) = it
   i=i+1
Next it
```

And then assigning the resulting array to the range.

Comment: the line `arr(i) = it` throws a *Subscript out of range (Error 9)*

Comment: Can you check the value of `i` with the debugger?

Comment: Worked when I set i = 0 first.

Comment: Ok i added this to my answer. Was it faster?

Comment: While not technically answering my question – to which the answer might just be *no* – this was **indeed** noticeably faster. It now wins both tests.

Comment: Oh, so your question was whether it is possible to directly "paste" the dictionary to the range... In this case no, I'm not aware of a way to do that. I think converting to an array is indeed your best bet. I will edit my answer to better fir your question.